# write FacePrinte in java

Tags: java

I got an assignment from my teacher and I have to complete it for tomorrow.

The assignment is : write a program FacePrinter that prints a face which hopefully looks better than this one.

```
    / / / / /  
  |   o   o   |
( |     ^     | )
  |           |
  |   [ __ ]  |
   \ _______ /
```

I already did this one but at the end of the assignment he says :

" Your program documentation should include your name, the programming assignment number and a brief description of what the program does "

Now my question is what should I write for this part and how can I include my name in the program?

Thank you

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Comment: Just put comments on the top (`/* comments go here */`).  Make sure its clean and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a simple comment at the top of the java file.

```
//Author: Your name
//Date: mm/dd/yyy
//Anything else: .f,lroifje
```

Comment: Thank you Tdorno. Now, what should I say for "brief description of what the program does?"

Comment: You should probably start by giving a "brief" description of what it does.